# COD BO3 campaign 4 players, 2 consoles offline

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

I gather you can setup campaign a max of 2 players for couch coop and 4 players for online, but is it possible to do 4 players offline just by connecting 2 consoles ( 2 player split screen on each console)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this website](http://www.co-optimus.com/article/13690/call-of-duty-black-ops-3-co-op-faq.html) you can play four player co-op through LAN. The response to the question: "How many players are supported in combo co-op?" is the following:

> Two players per system are supported in combo co-op with four players total being able to play the campaign and/or zombies mode.